# Two way binding is not updating datasource at all

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm creating a windows 8.1 phone app and I have data from a webservice that is the datasource for a grid. The problem I am having is when I click on one of the checkboxes, it is a two binding so the IsChecked property should be getting updated but it isn't. When I access the datasource, it is giving me the same data when it first loads the grid and the checkboxes stay checked. Here is the xaml code and below that is the code where it loads the datasource. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" Height="330" x:Name="scrollControl">
                <ItemsControl Name="lstTop10Picks">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="6" Name="gridTop11Stocks">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                                    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                                    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Market}" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Return}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>

var stocks = doc.Element(ns + "ArrayOfStockRating").Elements(ns + "StockRating")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            Id = count += 1,
            Symbol = n.Element(ns + "Symbol").Value,
            Market = n.Element(ns + "Market").Value,
            Return = n.Element(ns + "ShortRating").Value,
            IsChecked = false
        })
        .ToList();
lstTop10Picks.ItemsSource = stocks;
```

Comment: Anonymous types in C# are immutable so it doesn't matter if you declare the binding as two way. You need to declare a mutable type if you want it to work as you intended.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you show me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: @user3610374 He means rather than using `.Select(n => new { })` use `.Select(n => new ANewClass { })` - where `ANewClass` is a class that has get/set properties for each of your required properties.

Comment: scratch that. I just stumbled upon the answer accidentally

Comment: yep that is exactly what I accidentally figured out lol. Please create an answer and I will mark it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous types in C# are immutable. Meaning they cannot be changed once they are created. You need to declare your own type that is mutable to make the two-way binding work.

Something like:

```
public class StockViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Then to build your source collection:

```
var stocks = doc.Element(ns + "ArrayOfStockRating").Elements(ns + "StockRating")
    .Select((n, index) => new StockViewModel
    {
        Id = index + 1,
        Symbol = n.Element(ns + "Symbol").Value,
        Market = n.Element(ns + "Market").Value,
        Return = n.Element(ns + "ShortRating").Value,
        IsChecked = false
    }).ToList();
```

Note that I removed the side-effect in the LINQ query because that's just bad form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Property for binding like

```
 public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

if you have used

```
 public string MyProperty
```

then it won't work.